# Python: Create new dictionary from list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Good evening, I have this kind of list:

```
start_list = [
{u'body': u'Hello',
u'state': u'US',
u'user': {u'login': u'JON', u'id': 33}},
{u'body': u'Hola',
u'state': u'ES',
u'user': {u'login': u'PABLO', u'id': 46}}
]
```

I'd like to get a new list by extracting the dictionary from the 'user' key and get this result:

```
final_list = [
{u'body': u'Hello', u'state': u'US', u'login': u'JON', u'id': 33},
{u'body': u'Hola', u'state': u'ES',u'login': u'PABLO', u'id': 46}
]
```

I have already tested this code without success:

```
content = start_list[0]['user']
for element in start_list:
       final_list.append({key: elemento[key] for key in 
                       ["body","state",contenuto]})
```

is it possible to do a for loop in python to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a static dict schema, you can do this:

```
final_list = [{
    'body': d['body'],
    'state': d['state'],
    'login': d['user']['login'],
    'id': d['user']['id'],
} for d in start_list]
```

---

If your dict schema is big/dynamic, you can do this:

```
final_list = []
for d in start_list:
    r = {}
    for key in d['user']:
        r[key] = d['user'][key]
    for key in d:
        if key != 'user':
            r[key] = d[key]
    final_list.append(r)
```

---

If you want to modify `start_list` (do it in-place), you can do this:

```
for d in start_list:
    d.update(d['user'])
    d.pop('user')
```

Comment: thank you very much, you certainly deserve my positive vote but I don't have enough reputation